# Limit available groups for specific user in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

**Is it possible to limit the available groups that a user with the manage-membership permission can assign to other users?**

The scenario:

I have a `keycloak` instance with one `sub-realm`. There are `multiple groups (companies)` that are allowed to open the security-admin-console for this realm. I have 3 additional groups: **admin**, **poweruser**, **user**. I want powerusers to be able to create new users and assign them -> **only** <- to the group (company) they themselves belong to. With the manage-membership permission they are able to assign new users to all groups, even the admin group.

Is such a restriction possible or do I have to change my underlying concept?

Thanks
Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to set up a Multi-Tenancy solution only using a single realm. I would not advise trying to use this approach.

I have configured RedHatSSO (which is the paid version of KeyCloak) for multiple customers by using the following approach: Two realms per customer (company).

CompanyA_admin and CompanyA_user.

Groups can be configured to have admin privileges over other Realms. By using this approach, you can give admin privileges over the customer realm to users of the CompanyA_admin Realm, and normal users can be added to the CompanyA_user Realm with basic read-only access.

By doing this, your powerusers will have admin privileges but only over the Realms you have configured.

I believe the reason for the incorporation of "Realms" was to allow for your specific use case, and the logical separation of groups, or in your case, companies.

Comment: I'm trying to use a single realm because it's not really a multi-tenancy situation. I have one frontend from which all users (of all companies) can login in to keycloak. every now and than external companies (sometimes old ones are reused) are allowed to access the the system and manage their users by themselves (poweruser). I was hoping to avoid creating multiple realms as it makes everything much more complicated in my front- and backend. I will wait a day or so and if no other solution pops up I will check yours as the accepted answer. thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: it has been more than a few days. sorry for that. I just stumbled upon this thread at random :D

Comment: We are considering using one group per customer. We also think one realm per customer is much more complexe for frontend apps. There's also a limit for the number of realms you can use.